# Generating site in agregator project for all modules

Tags: maven

I created `aggregator pom` that is used to build `modules` in specific order.
It is in the same level as all other modules:

```
App
|_ aggregator
|_ module1 
|_ module2
|_ module3

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.crd</groupId>
<artifactId>aggregator</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Project Aggregator</name>

<modules>
    <module>../module1</module>
    <module>../module2</module>
    <module>../module3</module>
</modules>
```

When I run `mvn site`, it generates site under each module, i.e. `module1/target/site`

I would like for all modules: module1, module2, module3 sites to be generated under `aggregator/target/site`.

```
file:///C://eclipse-workspace/App/aggregator/target/site/index.html
```

Above aggregate index.html should contain link to module1, with URL:

```
file:///C://eclipse-workspace/App/aggregator/target/site/module1/index.html
```

Is this possible without introducing `<parent>` in all of the modules?
Or am I looking at this all wrong?

I tried many things, among few... `site:stage` and adding `<distributionManagement>` in each module and pointing to aggregator folder. Links were correct, but contents were empty.

Comment: checkout [site:stage mojo/goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/stage-mojo.html), this will...: "Deploys the generated site to a **local staging or mock directory** based on the **site URL** specified in the **<distributionManagement>** section of the POM. (you have to define!)
It can be used to **test that links between module sites in a multi-module build work**.

This goal *requires* the site to already have been generated using the *site goal*, such as by calling mvn site."

Comment: aok, sorry... easier: set `${project.reporting.outputDirectory}` in your parent pom! ;) (...to "fixed" location used by all children...)

Comment: @xerx593 It's not a parent-pom. That is my problem. What section do I add this to?

Comment: ..if you don't have a "parent pom" (at all), you must do it in every pom.. (if you don't have one, I recommend you to introduce!) "section", like: `<project><properties><project.reporting.outputDirectory>../path/to/site/${project.artifactId}</project.reporting.outputDirectory>...`

Comment: ..but if you suppose to run `mvn site` (only) from `aggregator`, then maybe it is enough in: `aggregator/pom.xml`